# What are the ''special class'' suru verbs on the jisho dictionary?

Tags: grammar, words

On jisho.org, words like ''達する'' are marked as ''Suru verb - special class''.
What is this so called ''special verb class?''

Comment: Related, maybe?? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5113/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46857/9831 ... Sorry if they are irrelevant..

Answer (score 6):

I think they are special because they have different conjugations from normal する-verbs, for example...

Regular する-verbs conjugate like...

> 勉強する → 勉強できる(potential) 勉強しよう(volitional) 勉強しない(negative)
>   理解する → 理解できる(potential) 理解しよう(volitional) 理解しない(negative)

The "special" する-verbs (i.e. verbs with ～す variants), conjugate like...

> 達する → 達せられる/?達せる(potential) 達しよう(volitional) 達しない/達さない(negative)
>   愛する → 愛せる(potential) 愛そう(volitional) 愛さない(negative)
>   訳する → 訳せる(potential) 訳そう(volitional) 訳さない(negative)

etc...

Comment: ムズい・・・ 達する、愛する、訳する、察する、は special verbs で、達す、愛す、訳す、察す、禁じる、は godan/ichidan だって～　ふえええ

Comment: 「 適する」と「適す」は同じ単語だと思う？

Comment: "The "special" する-verbs conjugate like... "って、実際に "suru verbs"についてじゃなくて、す五段動詞についてではないだろうか。少し分かりにくいんだけど。

Comment: 「適する」vs「適す」は、意味は同じですけど、形も活用も異なるので、「同じ単語」とは言えないと思います。[ここ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46878/9831)でブロッコリさんが書いている、 "variants" と呼ぶべきでしょうか。

Comment: 「愛する」「達する」「禁ずる」などは「す五段動詞」ではなく、「愛す」「達す」「禁ず・禁じる」などのvariantを持つ「サ変動詞(するverb)」です。辞書にも、「愛す」「適す」は「五段」、「愛する」「適する」は「サ変」、とあります。

Answer (score 2):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_irregular_verbs):

> These are single kanji suru forms. ‘While 〜する suru verbs following a
>   two-kanji compound are regular (using the admittedly irregular
>   conjugation of suru), behaving as a kanji noun followed by an
>   independent verb, there is irregular behavior for single
>   kanji suru verbs, and they behave as a single fused word, with various
>   forms and sometimes irregular conjugation. ‘

Below are some examples of single-kanji ‘special’ forms, compound forms, and regular verb forms. Note that meaning/nuance can change between the different forms:

> Single  - Double  -   Regular form
>
> 旅する   -   旅行する    -   X
>
> 反する   -   対抗する    -   反る
>
> 与する   -　  供与  -   与える
>
> 休する   -   休憩する    -   休む
>
> 生ずる   -   生起する    -   生きる
>
> 禁ずる   -   禁止する    -   X
>
> 要する   -   要求する    -   要る

In Japanese, these are called サ行変格活用 (irregular conjugation suru-form verbs).

There are pages of examples of these verbs and their meanings that can be found [here](https://www.japandict.com/lists/vs-s?page=1).

Comment: I came across this "special suru verbs" doubt myself during my studies, and I found this Q&A entry. I am trying to understand the topic. This answer looks coherent to me, but I'm hesitating to trust it since it's downvoted... any thoughts on why it might be incorrect? Thank you.

Comment: Aren't you mixing transitive and intransitive verbs here? For example, the meaning of 反する is 'to return something' (transitive), whereas 返る is 'to return' (intransitive). The transitive would be 返す.