# What kind of conjugation is 愛せない?

Tags: conjugations

I came across 愛せない in an example sentence in 新英和大辞典第５版 (under the entry 失格).

> 自分の子供を**愛せない**なんて母親失格だと思う。
> I don't think anyone who doesn't love her own child deserves the name of a mother.

What kind of conjugation is 愛せない?

Comment: Related: [What are the valid potential forms of special "suru" verbs?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5113/43676)

Comment: This is also kind of related: [Difference between 愛する and 愛す](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46857/43676)

Comment: Causative, negative. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation

Comment: @Meowzilla:  That is not correct, nor does it make sense in the context of the example sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the negative potential form of [愛す](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%84%9B%E3%81%99), which is a **godan** verb meaning "to love (someone)".

- **愛す** (godan, transitive): "to love"
- **愛せる** (potential form of 愛す): "can love"
- **愛せない** (negative form of 愛せる): "cannot love"
- (Compare) **愛さない** (negative form of 愛す): "does not love"

If you can read 泳げない, 笑えない, 待てない and so on, this is the same conjugation.

Note that 愛す(る) is a tricky verb that conjugates sometimes like a godan verb and sometimes like a suru-verb. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46878/5010), [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78047/5010) and [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56257/5010). When a potential meaning is involved, 愛できる doesn't make sense, and you need to say 愛せる (or 愛することができる).

Answer (score 0):

愛する (love) + せる (can) + ない (not)